# Pandas: Calculate neighbouring differences from a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I calculate the differences from neighboured numbers in a dataframe column named `'y'` by only using Pandas commands?

Here is an example where I convert the column `'y'`first to numpy and then use `np.diff`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(10)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10,2)),columns=['x', 'y'])

y=df['y'].values

diff_y=np.diff(y)

print(np.array([y[0:-1],diff_y]).T)

[[ 4 -3]
 [ 1 -1]
 [ 0  8]
 [ 8 -8]
 [ 0  6]
 [ 6 -3]
 [ 3  1]
 [ 4  4]
 [ 8  0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to find the differences and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to get the differences align (like in your output):

```
df['diff_y'] = df['y'].diff().shift(-1)
print(df[['y', 'diff_y']])
```

Output:

```
   y  diff_y
0  4    -3.0
1  1    -1.0
2  0     8.0
3  8    -8.0
4  0     6.0
5  6    -3.0
6  3     1.0
7  4     4.0
8  8     0.0
9  8     NaN
```

Comment: Please take a look at my following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706076/calculate-neighbouring-differences-from-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-after-gro